# Почему в пути отображаются по 2 копии каждого файла?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также и с другими папками. Создавал новые проекты тоже самое, работает все нормально но раздражает немного. Все папки имеют только оригинал.

Comment: Что-то у меня такое чувство что html и javacript здесь вовсе не причем. Это скорее вопрос к разработчикам редактора в котором Вы пишите этот html и js.

Comment: Фак, у меня 100500 расширений стоит

Comment: Какой у вас редактор? Atom?

Comment: Или вы используете Brackets?